# Three columns css layout + Togglable one

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create a 3 columns layout in css with a togglable one. The following scheme should explain it better than words.
[image]

I want the 3 columns be full height.

- In red: A static width column
- In green: A togglable menu
- In dark green: The menu after being toggled
- In white: The main container which should fill the rest of the page

I've tried to do it with the following code but without success:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="inline_container">
    <div id="left_menu"></div>
    <div id="toggle_menu"></div>
    <div id="main_container"></div>
</div>
```

And with this css code:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.body {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
#header {height: 70px; width: 100%;}
#inline_container {height: 95%; width: 100%;}
#left_menu {height: 100%; width: 80px; display: inline-block; float: left;}
#toggle_menu {height: 100%; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float: left;}
#main_container {height: 100%; width: 100%; display: inline-block; float: left;}
```

Comment: "_...without success._" Where did your attempt fail? Please be specific about what you expect to happen and what really happened. For bonus points, consider including a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: for start: don't specify `width: 100%` on your `main_container`. that will just put it in the next line, because it gets the with of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/47VDM/2/)**</kbd>

For creating full height page, you need a wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- MARKUP -->
</div>
```

That will fill the whole page:

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Inside our `wrapper`, we create our wanted elements:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="red"></div>

    <div id="lime">
        <div id="green"></div>
        <span class="close">[X]</span>
    </div>
    <div id="white">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `green` element is a child of `lime` element. If `lime` get class `collapsed`, all data
will be hidden and the `green` one will be display. Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#red {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#green {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    background: green;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#lime .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: pink;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#white {
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

#lime {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lime;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

#lime.collapsed {
    width: 30px;
}

#lime.collapsed * {
    display: none;
}

#lime.collapsed #green {
    display: block;
}
```

And for **closing** and **opening** the `lime` element, we need some JS (I used jQuery):

```
$(function () {
    $('#lime .close').on('click', function () {
        $('#lime').addClass('collapsed');
    });

    $('#green').on('click', function () {
        $('#lime').removeClass('collapsed');
    });
});
```

You can see the final [FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/47VDM/2/).

Answer (score 5):

Did you want something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kcfde/

I've added jQuery script to show toggle effect, just click the green div.

Basically, when you set `float` and `width`, elements should remain with `display: block`, as they'll fit in into content.

Comment: beat me to it =(  nice answer

Comment: Adding to Kamil's answer, here's the desired "effect" I think OP is looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/Qyvrv/2/